# change the texture frame of the sprite on touch

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

as a newbie to cocos2d i am stuccoed at this point i need to change the image(from sprite sheet also i am not using .plist for coordinates) of the sprite when touches began so for this purpose i used following code

```
elfSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"BowSpritesheet.png" capacity:12];
            [self addChild:elfSheet];
            elfFrame1 = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:elfSheet.texture rect:
                         CGRectMake(0, 0, 128, 140)]; //elf run00001.png
            elfFrame2 = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:elfSheet.texture rect:
                         CGRectMake(128, 0, 110, 140)]; //elf run00002.png

Bow = [CCSprite  spriteWithTexture:elfFrame1.texture rect:elfFrame1.rect];
            Bow.position=ccp(size.width/8, size.height/5);
            [elfSheet addChild:Bow z:0];
```

here `elfSheet` is `CCSpriteBatchNode`
now in cctouches began i need to change the sprite frame to `elfFrame2` when i tried set display frame it creates a crash

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [Bow setDisplayFrame:elfFrame2];//Creates a crash
}
```

please help me on this issue
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are over-releasing the CCSprite ( Bow ). [spriteWithTexture](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/develop-v2/cocos2d/CCSprite.m#L81) returns an autoreleased object , so you shouldn't be calling autorelease on it again.

Comment: thanks for the link, but as i told earlier i am not using .plist and also i am using sprite sheet which contains both the images i need to change to elf frame2 on touch

Comment: I'm confused by your comment. I made no mention of plists or spritesheets, but now that you mention it... along the same memory management lines, I'm guessing that elfFrame1 and elfFrame2 are not being retained properly, so by the time you try to use [Bow setDisplayFrame: elfFrame2]; , elfFrame2 is probably already an invalid reference.